# Wamp server MySQL - high performace ~500mb

Tags: mysql, wamp

I have a problem with my WampServer 2.5. MySQL 5.6.16 consumes 500 mb RAM memory. I have no databases, fresh installation. I set `table_definition_cache = 400` in `my.ini`, but this does not solve the problem. This is my.ini

```
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[wampmysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
table_definition_cache = 400
performance_schema=off
basedir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17
log-error=c:/wamp/logs/mysql.log
datadir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/data

lc-messages-dir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.17/share

# Change your locale here !
lc-messages=fr_FR

# Avoid warning
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = TRUE
# Disable Federated by default
skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
log-bin=mysql-bin

# binary logging format - mixed recommended
binlog_format=mixed

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)


# New for MySQL 5.6 if no slave
skip-slave-start


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir     = /tmp/     
#log-update     = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#innodb_data_home_dir = C:\mysql\data/
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = C:\mysql\data/
#innodb_log_arch_dir = C:\mysql\data/
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
#innodb_log_file_size = 5M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mysqld]
port=3306
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = TRUE
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you may have already seen an answer suggesting this change and the change is a good idea, but :-

Did you install the 64bit WAMPServer?

If you did there was a tiny bug that got through testing on the 64bit version of WAMPServer.

In the 64bit version of WAMPServer the name of the MySQL service was changed to `wampmysqld64` but they forgot to change the section name in the `my.ini` file accordingly.

So in `my.ini` change the section name to

```
# The MySQL server
[wampmysqld64]
```

The way MySQL works is to look at its own service name and then look in the `my.ini` for configuration setting under a section heading that matches its service name.

This should make MySQL pay attention to your config changes.